# Drip edge replacement

Tags: roof, roofing, gutters, soffit, flashing

The drip edge on my house is peeling back and wasn't noticed until significant water damage to the soffits occurred. Doesn't seem like it was ever actually fastened to the sheathing with nails, nor was it even touching it, rather it was just stuck to the tar paper. The shingles and underlayment overhang the sheathing by ~1.5". I live in Front Range Colorado and the affected section is on the west side of the house.

So a couple questions...

1. Is the drip edge 100% necessary here?
2. What's the fastest/easiest way to fix this?

[image: Under soffit]

[image: Gutter view]
[image: Drip edge view]

Comment: A) that's gutter flashing. B) there is no drip edge. ... Pry up the bottom row of shingles and put a ~1' strip of hot melt roll roofing (using nails), with it actually sticking out over the gutter. How to not have it not ice dam idk, but at least that'd be seasonal instead of always.